# ogr2ogr - conversion shapefile to kml - how to reduce the size of the output file?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, kml, ogr2ogr

Is possible to reduce the size of the `output.kml` file?

`ogr2ogr -f "KML" output.kml input.shx`

Answer (score 1):

The KMZ file format is just a zipped KML file, so much smaller. I think you can just zip the kml and rename it to kmz, but you can also create it that way using ogr2ogr, I'm pretty sure.